# Software to Watch Lectures

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there any software on Ubuntu that is a iTunes U replacement? I hate watching the lectures online because they go to slow for;most times I speed them up to 2x so I can get through them faster.

Answer (score 6):

tunes-viewer is  a good alternative...

here is more on that.
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/tunesviewer-itunes-university-media-and-podcasts-in-linux.html

Comment: And VLC will let you play at higher speed.